# How to solve a linear system of equations in Matlab without LU and without pivoting?

Tags: matlab, math, linear-algebra

I wrote the code for LU factorization , for partial pivoting and also for full pivoting . 
Now , I want to find the "real" solution of the equation `A*x = b` . The real solution is without using pivoting (partial/full) , and no LU factorization .

How can I do this in matlab ? I guess it should be a single saved word , but not `linsolve` ,since 
it uses `LU factorization with partial pivoting when A is square and QR factorization with column pivoting otherwise` .

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `A` invertible?

If so, then

```
x= A\b; %This is preferred to x=inv(A)*B;
```

should do the trick. If `A` is singular you can use the `svd()` command to find its pseudo-inverse.

Comment: Why use svd to find a pseudo-inverse, when pinv is there for your use already? Don't reinvent the wheel.